# Expand all environment variables in string (Format string)

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, environment-variables

I need to expand all the variables inside a string to format the string.

For example if I have this string:

```
%homedrive%\blabla\%Username%\blabla\%computername%\%PercentCharacters%blabla
```

I want to format the string to obtain this:

```
X:\blabla\MyUsername\blabla\MyComputername\%PercentCharacters%blabla
```

I know how to expand a variable, but which is the better improved way to do it in this case? maybe with a regex group to match all the %vars% and to check if the match is a real var or are percent characters? how to do it?

Someone can showme an example?

> UPDATE:

This is my intent, I'm able to expand the real environment vars preserving the non-real vars, but I'm stucked trying to detect the "\bla\" parts in the same group to append them to the string.

```
Dim str As String = "%homedrive%\bla\%username%\bla\%computername%\%chars%\bla"
' MsgBox(Expand_Variables(str))

Private Function Expand_Variables(ByVal str As String) As String

    Dim TempStr As String = String.Empty

    Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, <a><![CDATA[(%\w+%)]]></a>.Value)

    Do While match.Success
        TempStr &= Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(match.NextMatch().ToString)
    Loop

    Return TempStr

End Function
```

> UPDATE 2:

Done, But I want to know if I can improve my code:

```
Public Function Expand_Variables_In_String(ByVal str As String) As String

    Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = _
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, "(%\w+%)")

    Do While match.Success
        str = str.Replace(match.ToString, Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(match.ToString))
        match = match.NextMatch()
    Loop

    Return str

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not replace?

Sorry, I didn't notice it was VB.Net. My original answer was in C#, I haven't used VB in years, but here is the code for vb.

```
Dim strpath as String
strpath = "%homedrive%\blabla\%Username%\blabla\%computername%\%PercentCharacters%blabla"
strpath.Replace("%homedrive%","X:").Replace("%Username%","blabla").Replace("%computername%","MyComputerName")
```

Comment: Thanks but the code does not help me. "Why not replace?": If I try to replace a "non-real" variable then your suggestion will fail, also the system can have custom environment variables added by the user, and also really I don't want to append to the string the .replace function x35 times for the 35 default Windows environment variables (is not for lazy things) it is too much incorrect to use your code suggestion even for newbie programmers, I need a improved ways to do this using regex (for example) but anyways thanks.

Comment: If you didn't use regex, then instr and mid in a loop would work then

Comment: Thanks again but that is more or less the same thing that using a replace, also that are VB6 funcs, not native vb.net. Sorry I need to remember you I'm looking for an improved way to do this, not to use thousand replaces (or left,mid) or to reference/import Microsoft.VisualBasic6 libray to use obsolete functions and/or to do a loop over the string.